# Spring RestTemplate HTTP POST with non standard HTTP header causes 400 bad request error

Tags: java, spring, post, http-headers, resttemplate

I am sending a POST request to a service with custom header and payload, via RestTemplate. On executing 'exchange' method, I am getting 400 Bad request error. However, same request works fine when sent from Chrome Postman plugin.

After so much debugging, I have found the root cause for it, it's happening due to non standard http header being present in headers. Below is the code to create header object:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.set("Authorization", "token");
headers.set("X-User-name", "user");
```

Request with this header results in 400. Now, if I comment out the last line, I get 500 error from server, asking for header. However, this means request is valid.

Can anyone please help?

**Update**

I tried removing hyphens from header name (e.g. tried with XUsername) and got the message from server, saying X-User-name is required. So, it has something to do with hyphen symbol.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this header being used for some sort of authentication?

Comment: Yes.. It is used to log the username.

Comment: Can you post the server log from a request when the error occurs?  Are you _certain_ the request be the same in RestTemplate and Chrome Postman?

Comment: Actually, I am getting `HttpClientErrorException`. So don't think the request goes to server. When I printed the response, I got org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Bad Request".

Comment: Something smells fishy here...sending the _same_ requests to the service should generate the _same_ results.  BTW...the hyphen has nothing to do with it...you passed in the wrong header name that's all.

Comment: A 400 response from a spring service is usually a mismatch between the `@RequestMapping` and the actual parameters/headers/entity. Please post the relevant controller method for your service.